# Getting the value of a parent node element in XSL

Tags: xslt

Unfortunately the xsl outputs the same ShortName entry for each section with this construct:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Questionnaire/Section">
<xsl:for-each select="Item">
<xsl:value-of select="Question"/></strong>
<xsl:for-each select="Optionlist/option">       
<input type="radio" > 
<xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="//ShortName" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

The XML:

```
<Questionnaire>
<Section><Title>Available Data</Title>
<Item>
<ShortName>Name</ShortName>
<Optionlist>
<option><entry>Yes</entry></option></Optionlist>
</Item>
</Section>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems instead of the path `//ShortName` you want `ancestor::Item/ShortName`.

Comment: Many thanks may be there ist more than one solution- I also found this works: 
    <xsl:variable name="item" select="."/> 
    <xsl:for-each select="Optionlist/option">
    <td>
    <input type="radio" > 
    <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="$item/ShortName" /></xsl:attribute>